# bullets firing at weird angles pygame

Tags: python, pygame, vector-graphics

I'm coding a 2d top down shooter in pygame and I'm running into an issue with the vector graphics of the bullet i'm trying to fire.  The bullets are firing, but they're not firing towards the cursor like they should.  I've encountered this before and I know it's got something to do with my bullet move function code, which I've provided below, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

to see the weird angle they're firing at run the full file here https://github.com/hailfire006/economy_game/blob/master/shooter_game.py

```
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self,mouse,player):
        self.x = player.x
        self.y = player.y
        self.name = "bullet"
        self.speed = 13
        self.mouse = mouse
        self.dx,self.dy = self.mouse
    def move(self):
        distance = [self.dx - self.x, self.dy - self.y]
        norm = math.sqrt(distance[0] ** 2 + distance[1] ** 2)
        direction = [distance[0] / norm, distance[1] / norm]
        bullet_vector = [direction[0] * self.speed, direction[1] * self.speed]

        self.x -= bullet_vector[0]
        self.y -= bullet_vector[1]

    def draw(self):
        square = pygame.Rect((self.x,self.y),(20,20))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(200,100,40),square)
```

edit: fixed the typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 issues with your code. @DTing already mentioned the typo. That made the bullets head in the opposite direction.

To get the bullets to fire in the same direction as the mouse click you need to change the following lines:

```
self.x -= bullet_vector[0]
self.y -= bullet_vector[1]
```

to

```
self.x += bullet_vector[0]
self.y += bullet_vector[1]
```

Now your bullets are going in the right direction but they will stop once they reach the spot where your mouse click occurred. This is because you are getting the bullet vector with each move. You can get it once in the init function and they just reuse it with each successive call. Here are the changes I made to get the code working:

```
def __init__(self,mouse,player):
    self.x = player.x
    self.y = player.y
    self.name = "bullet"
    self.speed = 13
    self.mouse = mouse
    self.dx,self.dy = self.mouse
    distance = [self.dx - self.x, self.dy - self.y]
    norm = math.sqrt(distance[0] ** 2 + distance[1] ** 2)
    direction = [distance[0] / norm, distance[1] / norm]
    self.bullet_vector = [direction[0] * self.speed, direction[1] * self.speed]

def move(self):
    self.x += self.bullet_vector[0]
    self.y += self.bullet_vector[1]
```

Your code will now work as expected.

Comment: Nice. Stoping at the cursor could be intentional, depending on the game.

Comment: @DTing I think you make a great point there. I wasn't sure if it was suppose to stop so I just had it keep going. A student made a game were the bullet stopped at the cursor and then exploded. That game was a lot of fun.

Comment: I didn't think about the fact that it would stop.  Now that you mention it I'll have to decide which one I do want, but thanks to you guys I'll have the option of either!

Answer (score 3):

The naming of your variables is somewhat confusing but I'm pretty sure this is a typo:

```
    distance = [self.dx - self.x, self.dy, self.y]
```

Should be:

```
    distance = [self.dx - self.x, self.dy - self.y]
```

Comment: Hmm okay i'll take another look.